# How can I get the id of the user that makes a request

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

How can I get the id of the user that creates a new article. I have created my auth middleware already with JWT. Here is my create article code.

```
exports.createArticle = (req, res) => {
  const { title, article } = req.body;
  const query = {
    text: 'INSERT INTO article (title, article) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *',
    values: [title, article],
  };
  pool
    .query(query)
    .then((response) => {
      const { id, created_on } = response.rows[0];
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Article successfully posted',
        articleId: id,
        createdOn: created_on,
        title,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        error,
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: where is your middleware, and what is the information(just fields) that you are providing as a payload to create a token with jwt.

Comment: How to access the identity information of the user on the `req`uest object should be part of the documentation of your auth middleware. Since you haven't told us which one you are using, or showed the code where you set it up, we cannot help you with that.

Comment: I don't see what this question has to do with postgres specifically.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a **payload** that has the user's id in it, and then passing it to `jwt.sign()` then you can get the id of the user, once you **authenticate** the user's request by validating **token** that is being sent with the **request**.

**Steps:**

> **Note:**
>
> this are just a simple steps for better understanding, 
>   ignore syntax or anything too specific to errors etc.

1. User sends log-in request.
2. you validate the credentials and send a token to the client side.

   ```
   payload = { userId: userId , //rest info}

   toekn = jwt.sign(payload, "key")

   // send the token back, your methods may vary
   ```
3. User request for article creation and you receive token in the request, cookies, header or any other mechanism that you use
4. you use middleware to authenticate the request with token

   ```
   jwt.verify(token, "key", (err, decodedUserInfo) => {
        //dont proceed if err just throw error

        //this decodedInfo has all the info that you have in payload while creating the token in step 2.

         req.user = decodedUserInfo;
         next();
   }
   ```
5. as your req object has user info now, once your middleware is passed, you can use this info in your further operations.

Comment: now you are exposing an internal reference to a user together with an authorization token.

Comment: I liked this `subjectId` idea, I would like to know more about it.

Comment: updated my answer to show how to get the subject id from the token. The subject id is a unique identifier provided by the issuing server to identify that subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that from the JWT claims. Here is a list of standard claims: [JWT Claims](https://www.iana.org/assignments/jwt/jwt.xhtml).

Subject, email, name or nickname would be suitable, depending on your case.

If you need an internal id, such as a database primary key - then use the subject id to link to that internal id. It is not considered good practice to leak out internal references to the outside.

[image: Propsed Architecture]

How to get the subject id:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
// this is just for test, get a real verified token from your middleware
const testToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c";
const token = jwt.decode(testToken);
let subjectId = token.sub; // then lookup and insert into database
```

You can find out more by reading the OpenID Connect specification here: [OpenID Connect Specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html) section 2.2 for the ID Token part.

Comment: In my db I have user and article table, so I want the userId of the user that created the article to show in the article table. How can I go about it?

Comment: One way is to create a lookup table in that database, that links the user id of the user to the subject id of the token. Use a common way to determine the user such as email to lookup in the user table.